# How do I only copy array to another spreadsheet if array is not empty? Receiving no length defined error on Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm very new to coding/Google Appscript so forgive me. I am trying to copy data between spreadsheets which matches certain criteria. My problem is, if the array returns no rows which match I get an error 'TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined'. Is there a way to skip copying the data if the array is null?

```
function myFunction() {
  var sourcess = SpreadsheetApp.openById();
  var sourcedata = sourcess.getSheetByName('debt data'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sourcedata.getRange('Q:Q'); //range to check
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var testrange2 = sourcedata.getRange('R:R');
  var testvalue2 = testrange2.getValues();
  var targetss = SpreadsheetApp.openById();
  var targetdata = targetss.getSheetByName('Debtors'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];
  var lastRow = targetdata.getLastRow();
  for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
    if ( testvalue[i] != '123' && testvalue2[i] == 'abc') {
      data.push.apply(data,sourcedata.getRange(i+1,1,1,20).getValues());  
      j.push(i); 
    }
  }
  targetdata.getRange(lastRow+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ranges Like this: `sourcedata.getRange('Q:Q');` often result in a lot of null items because they collect all of the cells down to Max Rows.

It would be better to use `sourcedata.getRange(1,17,sourcedata.getLastRow(),1);`

This: `if ( testvalue[i] != '123' && testvalue2[i] == 'abc')`

needs to be like this: `if ( testvalue[i][0] != '123' && testvalue2[i][0] == 'abc')`

Even single column arrays require two indices.

I would write this:

`data.push.apply(data,sourcedata.getRange(i+1,1,1,20).getValues());`

like this:

`data.push.(sourcedata.getRange(i+1,1,1,20).getValues()[0]);`

Actually, I wouldn't have done it that way at all. I would do something like this:

`var vA=sourcedata.getRange(1,1,sourcedata.getLastRow(),20).getValues();`

and then `data.push(vA[i]);//and that gets the whole row of 20 columns as a flattened array`

**Here's an example of something similar to what you are doing I think.**

My Source Sheet Looks Like this:

[image]

My Destination Sheet Looks Like this:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
function copyDataIfAB() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet187');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var hA=vA[0];
  var hObj={};
  var sA=[];
  hA.forEach(function(e,i){if(e){hObj[e]=i}});
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(vA[i][hObj['HDR2']]=='A' && vA[i][hObj['HDR10']]=='B') {
      sA.push(vA[i]);
    }
  })
  var tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Id');
  var tsh=tss.getSheetByName('Sheet9');
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1,sA.length,sA[0].length).setValues(sA);//appending it to the next empty row on the sheet
}
```